# How to provide straight access to usb wifi adapter in virtualbox(guest OS is win7 x64) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS host

Tags: 16.04, networking, usb, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Samsung RF511-S08RU and usb wifi adapter Tenda U1. 
I want to provide access to this adapter in virtualbox(Version 5.2.0 r118431 (Qt5.6.1)) with Win7 x64 guest OS.
When I try to add usb device in virtual machine's settings it does not appear there(in list of usb devices).
Also, I don't want to attach it just in bridge network mode. I need to get full control on this device in guest OS(plug it into virtual machine like usb device).
I have installed VirtualBox Extension Pack already. 
So how can I do it? Please someone help me!

Comment: Is your user account added to the `vboxusers` group?  Type in `groups` from a terminal and it will show you all your groups that you are part of.

Comment: @Terrance No, I'm not in vboxusers group. I add my user in it. So what I have to do next?

Comment: From a terminal window type in `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER`.  Then I suggest that you reboot the computer for the changes to take effect.  Then you should be able to access your USB devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method known as "PCI Passthrough" which will allow your VM to access directly *some* physical devices.  This extension to VirtualBox is not installed by default, and it is considered by the VirtualBox people to by *experimental*.

As this is a development feature, and not a development feature of Ubuntu or Linux, support on this website will be very limited.  I would suggest that you read through [The Virtual Box Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough) for instructions about pre-conditions and installation instructions for PCI passthrough, and sign up to the [Virtual Box Community](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Community) for support on this subject.

Comment: Thank u a lot! I will follow links above to clarify this situation.